# Anonymous Edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It seems as though more and more I see the "Suggested Edits" reviews being populated with anonymous users. Why is this? Why does Stack Exchange allow anonymous users to edit a post that can potentially completely change or make an invalid edit. Who knows if it's the original user that forgot to login, making a relevant edit, or someone else replying to the post when they should be answering or commenting.

This is just an example of spam, but very relevant:

[image]

Comment: Always assume it's a different user. The worst that can happen is that they go "Oh, darnit" and log in to make the change.

Comment: Related meta thread: http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/979/increase-of-spam-bots-on-edits